# Bayesian modeling of data at different cluster level

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, jags

I have the following data:

[image]

The response variable Y and the independent variable X2 were collected at state level (lowest level), while X1 are only available at country level.

The general form of my mixed effect model looks like:

Y = constant + x1 + x2 + random_state

My challenge is that X1 is only available at country level.

How can I correctly account for this, should I include X1 as random slope ?

I am not sure how to handle this. Any suggestion will be very useful.